# MP3 & MP4 audio and video not working firefox

Tags: audio, video, mp3, embed, mp4

Have tried the HTACCESS fixes all the clear this rest start that fixes and still nothing, scripts work in IE, Opera, Chrome but not Firefox....HELP!!!!

```
    <video show controls class="embed-responsive-item">
    <source src="uploads\video\<?php echo $rows['File_Attached']; ?>"  
    type="video/mp4">
    </video>

   <audio preload="auto" controls>
    <source src="uploads\audio\<?php echo $rows['File_Attached']; ?>" > 
   </audio>
```

Comment: Seem there may be an issue with paths, the path to the file seem ok in all other browser but not in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem to be the path to the file, all other browsers understand upload/video/file.mp4 for example but firefox wanted upload\video\file.mp4 
which all other browsers understand as well... note to self remember the correct path.